# Multiple endpoints of Microsoft Cognitive Services simultaneously

Tags: node.js, request, azure-cognitive-services, azure-api-apps

So I'm writing an app in Node.js which analyses sentiment and extracts key phrases using Microsoft Cognitive services. To do these two separate things, I use two nested POST calls, one starting when the other finishes. However, this seems inefficient. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quickstarts/nodejs) mentions that, to examine sentiment for example, the URL 'must **contain** /sentiment', not that it must be the only endpoint for that one call. Perhaps I could do both in one call and save myself Azure budget and execution time?

I have tried /sentiment/keyPhrases, that returns 404. /sentiment/../keyPhrases just does keyPhrases. I cannot think of another way to combine the two endpoints.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to use a single endpoint for multiple calls, so they must be done separately.

Comment: I did doubt it, but the wording of the API documentation confused me. Thought I’d ask just in case. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Never hurts to ask :)

Comment: Since I can’t mark a comment as an accepted answer, should I just post an answer and accept it?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was mislead by my understanding of the documentation. Endpoints must be called separately, and the answers can be combined in Node afterwards using `response = response1.concat(response2);`.